# Clearing tests in selenium Webdriver after 50 tests

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I've written long test suite in Selenium Webdriver (over 100 tests), in Java and TestNG. 
When I launch only last group of tests (name 'v1870'), under 20 tests, I alvays got successes after tests. But when I launch all of test, I've got some filures in tests from groups the last group.

I use annotation, for clearing driver:

```
    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    if (driver != null) {
        driver.quit ();
    }
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString ();
    if (!"".equals (verificationErrorString)) {
        Assert.fail (verificationErrorString);
    }
}
```

For some reasons, Ive got failures. (assertion errors or *org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?*)

What should I do to clear all necessary things?
For instance, I thing, that I could clear everything after 20 classes/tests, but how?

Comment: You could create a new driver before and quit after each test  to see if it still fails by using "@Before" and "@After". Maybe it is a particular test that causes the problem.

Comment: Thanks for advice!

Comment: I have seen, that TestNG open new window, when there is "driver.get(some url)" and the same priority (in @Test annotation) for more then one test. So I changed priority each test to unique (numbers based on version) and it helped :)